# Will a 20 amp Siemens GFCI work in a 1966 ITE EQ Loadcenter that does not have a separate neutral bar?

Tags: electrical

1966 ITE EQ residential load Center. I want to install a 20 amp Siemens GFCI breaker for the 2010 pool pump. There is no separate neutral bar. I already bought the breaker.  I have a separate 70 amp Square D QO load center for part of the house. How do install the GFCI in the ITE panel without a separate neutral bar?

Comment: In a main panel, the ground and neutrals are electrically connected, so it doesn't matter that you don't have separate neutral and ground bars. So if the breaker is rated and compatible with the panel, you'd just run the curly little pig tail to the neutral/ground bar and connect the pool pump neutral and hot to the GFCI  breaker.  I'm posting this as a comment rather than an answer bc I'm not sure if the breaker is compatible with your panel.   Hopefully one of the "big 3" will comment or answer.

Comment: I have looked up ITE in the past and they were compatible with Siemens QP. 
The other square D load center is irrelevant.

Comment: The other panel is relevant, @EdBeal if the answer is "no, it's not compatible, put a breaker in the other panel if there's room". Usually, there's not nearly enough info in these questions, so it's refreshing to see one with some "extra".

Comment: @freeman a Siemens breaker will not mate up to a square D QO panel. you cannot use it with that breaker so it is irrelevant with the question of how to install a Siemens breaker in Alan ITE panel.

Comment: Poorly worded. The answer could be "No, that breaker won't work in the ITE, it will be hard to find one that will, therefore get one for the Square D QO panel instead."

Comment: Oh, a Siemens breaker will mate up with the QO, it'll fit almost like it's meant to.  It will then *burn up*, and possibly take a lot of other stuff out with it.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica -- that's Homeline :P QO busbar stabs are "sideways" (flat strips vs poky "tabs") compared to everyone else, so nothing else will even fit to begin with

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of your ITE panel? Also, I'm pretty sure what you have is a panel that only has a neutral bar or bars...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel *foreheadslap* oh right.